# ACF Field in WordPress Custom REST End Point

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this method to create a custom API endpoint the method is defined as following code.
This code is working fine But the ACF field is showing as false.In this code my Advanced Custom Field value  is `url`

```
function help_faq_data() {
$args = [
    'numberposts' => 99999,
    'post_type' => 'help-center'
];

// get posts
$posts = get_posts($args);
$data = [];
$i = 0;

foreach($posts as $post) {
    $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
    $data[$i]['foo'] = get_field('url', $post->ID);
    $i++;
   }
    return $data;
 }

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
register_rest_route('help-center-api/v1', 'faq-data', [
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'help_faq_data',
   ]);
});
```

**Result:**

```
{
   "id": 190,
   "foo": false
}, etc..
```

Comment: Are you sure the ACF url field actually has a value for post 190? Also, instead of 99999 `numberposts` you can just set it to -1.

Comment: Yes i have value. I am getting other data but not the value from Advanced Custom Field

Comment: Normally, it should work like this but try using the field key (e.g., `field_5c629deadbeef`) of the url-field instead of `'url'`. And you can try `debug_log('get_field for url: '.json_encode(get_field_object('field_5c629deadbeef', $post->ID)));` to inspect what this returns.